# How to scan a single file using Sonar Runner

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Is there any way to scan a single java file using sonar runner.

By default all the java files in the **scr***. I do not want to exclude all the other files by writing a exclusion. Rather I would like to include only a single file for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Check for sonar.inclusions and how it works. This can give you a better idea.